# MySQL unsigned int total with deleted rows?

Tags: mysql, unsigned-integer

I understand the total MySQL unsigned int is 4,294,967,295
Lets says I used all rows but then delete 10 rows will I be able to use the additional 10 rows i just deleted 4,294,967,295 + 10?

Basically if I delete 10 rows after filling my total column ID with 4,294,967,295 rows will I get additional 10 more rows because I deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you will not.

It is possible to search for the gaps and bypass auto-increment to fill them, but this pretty much defeats the purpose of using auto-increment.

Use `BIGINT` if you need more rows.